# Spring MVC trying to get parameter from redirect in GET request method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I POST a form to the server and once the form is sucessful i want to redirect to another page however i want to send values to the redirect page which has a GET request. I am not getting the values to pass:

**Error**
I am getting a HTTP 400 Bad Request error

**Code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "crime_registration_save.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView handleSave(@Valid @ModelAttribute Crime crime,BindingResult result, ModelMap m, Model model) throws Exception {



        if (result.hasErrors()) {

            logger.debug("Has Errors In crime_registration_save");
            model.addAttribute("dbcriminals", myCriminalList);
            model.addAttribute("dbvictims", myVictimList);
            model.addAttribute("status", myStatusList);
            model.addAttribute("crimeCategory", myCrimeCategoryList);
            model.addAttribute("crimeLevel", myCrimeLevelList);
            model.addAttribute("officers", myOfficerList);

            model.addAttribute("victimList", crime.getVictims());
            model.addAttribute("criminalList", crime.getCriminals());

            model.addAttribute("crimeTypeList",
                    crimeTypeManager.getCrimeTypeList(crime.getOffenceCatId()));
            model.addAttribute("icon", "ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close");
            model.addAttribute("results", "Error: Unable to Save Record!");

            return new ModelAndView("crime_registration");
        }
        logger.debug("No errors going to preform save");

        int crimeRecNo;

        crimeRecNo = crimeManager.saveCrime(crime); 

        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("monitoringList.htm")); 
    }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @RequestMapping(value = "monitoringList.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView handleMonitoring(@RequestParam(value="crimeRecNo", required=true) Integer crimeRecNo, HttpServletRequest request,  
            HttpServletResponse response ,Model model) throws Exception {


        model.addAttribute("crimeRecNo", crimeRecNo);



        return new ModelAndView("monitoringList"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RedirectView passes the model objects to the url. In your example, there is no model being returned from the post handler method.

Try this, and it should work for you:

```
return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("monitoringList.htm"), "crimeRecNo", crimeRecNo);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way i can hide the parameter from the user in the url so they wont see the crimeRecNo ?

Comment: The only way you can hide the parameter is to use a hacky sesion scope attribute method. I call it hacky because it is counter intuitive.. After a post, the reason for presenting a GET request is to make sure the user gets an idempotent url. A url that the user can load several times, without any adverse effects.. if this GET link does not contain the id of the data it is trying to fetch, but instead it relies on a session attribute, the url is no longer idempotent. If the user loads the URL at a later time, it might not even work, or point to the record currently in the session.

Comment: I tried encrypting the parameter value however i ran into some issues can you look at this for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259118/encryption-and-decryption-using-blowfish-error-input-length-must-be-multiple-o