# Encryption and Decryption using Blowfish Error - Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher

Tags: java, encryption, blowfish

I am able to encrypt data however when decrypting it i am getting the following error:

**Error**

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

**Here is my Encryption and Decryption code**

```
//secret key 8 
    private static String strkey ="Blowfish";
```

**UPDATED**

```
 //encrypt using blowfish algorithm
    public static byte[] encrypt(String Data)throws Exception{

        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(strkey.getBytes("UTF8"), "Blowfish");
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
         cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

         return (cipher.doFinal(Data.getBytes("UTF8")));

    }

    //decrypt using blow fish algorithm
    public static String decrypt(byte[] encryptedData)throws Exception{
         SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(strkey.getBytes("UTF8"), "Blowfish");
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
         cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
         byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
         return new String(decrypted); 

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run your encrypt and decrypt methods in a main method, it will work. But if the results of encrypt are put into a url and then the url parameter is decrypted, it will fail.

After encryption, the byte array contains values that are outside the character set of URLS (non-ascii), so this value gets encoded when it is stuffed into a url. And you you receive a corrupted version for decryption.

As an example, when I created a string from an encrypted byte array, it looked like this `Ž¹Qêz¦` but if I put it into a URL it turns into `Ž%0B¹Qêz¦`.

The fix, as suggested in other comments, is to add a encode / decode step. After encryption, the value should be encoded to a format which contains ascii characters. Base 64 is an excellent choice. So you return encrypted and encoded value in the url. When you receive the param, first decode then decrypt, and you'll get the original data.

Here are some notes on the implementation.

1. Use a library like commons codec. It is my weapon of choice, this class specifically http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html.
2. In the class that does encryption and decryption, have a shared instance of `Base64`. To instantiate it use `new Base64(true);` this produces url safe strings.
3. Your encrypt and decrypt method signatures should accept and return strings, not byte arrays.
4. So the last line of your encrypt would become something like `return base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(Data.getBytes("UTF8")));` You can now safely pass the encrypted value in a url
5. In your decrypt, you first step is to decode. So the first line would become something like `byte[] encryptedData = base64.decodeBase64(encrypted);`

I just took your code and added some base 64 stuff, the result looks like this:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;


public class Test {

    private static String strkey ="Blowfish";
    private static Base64 base64 = new Base64(true);

     //encrypt using blowfish algorithm
    public static String encrypt(String Data)throws Exception{

        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(strkey.getBytes("UTF8"), "Blowfish");
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
         cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

         return base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(Data.getBytes("UTF8")));

    }

    //decrypt using blow fish algorithm
    public static String decrypt(String encrypted)throws Exception{
        byte[] encryptedData = base64.decodeBase64(encrypted);
         SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(strkey.getBytes("UTF8"), "Blowfish");
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
         cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
         byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
         return new String(decrypted); 

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String data = "will this work?";
        String encoded = encrypt(data);
        System.out.println(encoded);
        String decoded = decrypt(encoded);
        System.out.println(decoded);
    }
}
```

Hope this answers your questions.

Comment: I am getting the following error in the class The constructor Base64(boolean) is undefined for  private static Base64 base64 = new Base64(true);

Comment: Can you give me some advice on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290808/spring-mvc-url-mapping-in-controller-for-dynamic-urls?noredirect=1#comment23324237_16290808

Comment: Can you also look at this question for me please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305926/springmvc-looping-through-list-data-passed-from-the-view

Comment: @devdar Base64 is in the pakage org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a String out of random (in this case encrypted) bytes like you're doing in the last line of your encrypt method - you need to create a [Base64 encoded string](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) instead (which you then need to decode back to a byte array in the decrypt method).  Alternatively, just have your encrypt method return a byte array and have your decrypt method accept a byte array as its parameter.

Comment: I am not sure i understand fully i should remove the cipher.doFinal and just do Data.getBytes("UTF8")?

Comment: Remove the `new String` part, keep the `return cipher.doFinal(Data.getBytes("UTF8"))` part; change `encrypt` so that it returns a `byte[]` instead of a `String`, and change `decrypt` so it takes a `byte[] encryptedData`

Comment: Try testing the two methods from a `main` method or a `test` method to isolate them from the rest of your program - I suspect that you've got another method in there that's corrupting the byte array

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the way you are creating `String` instances out of the raw encrypted `byte[]` data. You need to either use binhex encoding like that provided by [`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) via the `parseHexBinary` and `printHexBinary` methods or base 64 using the `parseBase64Binary` and `printBase64Binary` methods of the same object.

One other word of advice, never rely on the default mode and padding, always be explicit. Use something like `Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding")` depending on what your needs are.