# Spring MVC URL mapping in controller For dynamic URLs

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller, url-mapping

I have a page with part of a URL that is dynamic e.g.

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/myPageList.htm?recNo=107&recNo=-96&recNo=-24&recNo=-9&recNo=38&recNo=-21&recNo=-50&crimeRecNo=-110
```

The last part of the page recNo is a parameter passed to the page. However, the parameter value was encrypted. I would like to know how I can set the `urlMapping` in the controller. I will be posting the data and i will require a `urlMapping` to process this form.

Comment: When you say `urlMapping`, do you mean how to map the request with `@RequestMapping`?

Comment: @zeroflagL yes thats what i mean

Comment: I dont understand.. what do you mean the last parameter was encrypted? is this the exact url being fired from the page to the controller?

Comment: And what's the dynamic part? You do not mean everything behind `myPageList.htm?`, I guess.

Comment: No every thing to the right of myPageList.htm. Actually i was wondering if the Controller would look at that part of the url and maybe the mapping should just be /myPageList.htm? I am not sure

Comment: I did some encryption to the parameter form the GET so thats why it looks like that after the myPageList.htm... now i want to POST the page to the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your comments your request mapping should be

```
@RequestMapping("/myPageList.htm")
```

And the signature of your method something like

```
public WhateverType myPageList(@RequestParam("recNo") List<Integer> recNo, ...
```

assuming that `recNo` are integer values.

Comment: why should it be List<Integer> recNo ? the encryption did something like {12,44,65,17..} i think thats how the encrypted parameter looked hence after the url recNo=12&recNo=44,recNo=65........ Is that part necessary or can i just have myPageList(@RequestParam("recNo") Integer recNo

Comment: Your sample request url has multiple `recNo` parameters. If you only have an `Integer` then which one of those values should the Controller use? I have no idea, of course, what those parameters mean. So it's up to you to use them correctly :)

Comment: can you give me some advice on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305926/springmvc-looping-through-list-data-passed-from-the-view

Answer (score 0):

Using `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` ([doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.html) [sample](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-simpleurlhandlermapping-example/))might help.

Have a look at `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s10.html), as well